# Get email pic_for with looping

Tags: laravel, loops

I have a table structure like this

```
id |       name     |         email            | pic_for
1        Michael       michael.john@gmail.com            
2       John Doe       john.doe@gmail.com            1
3      Lorem Ipsum       lorem@ipsum.com             2
4      Dolor Amet        dolor@amet.com              1
5       En Ciel            en@ciel.com
```

So the stucture is like

```
1
|- 2 , 4
   |-3

5
```

In the case above, I need to check if another user (user 2) has been person in charge for the person (user id 1), and then check again if user 2 have another person in charge or not.

I have tried code, and the result I get is

```
array:6 [▼
0 => 2
1 => 3
2 => 5
3 => 4
4 => 3
5 => 5
]
```

What I need is I get the result like

```
array:4 [▼
0 => 2
1 => 3
2 => 5
3 => 4
]
```

Here's the code

```
$query = DB::table('users')->where('pic_for',$id)->get();
//dd($query);
        foreach ($query as $q) 
        {

            $dum[]=$q->id;
            //dd($dum);
            $query2 = DB::table('users')->where('pic_for',$dum)->get();
            //dd($query);
            foreach ($query2 as $q2)
            {
                $dum[]=$q2->id; 
            }

        }
    dd($dum);
```

Is there something that I have missed ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of the while loop here? It's essentially running the exact same query as your first one. The reason you're not getting id 3 is because you're query is saying `pic_for=1` and the id 3 has a `pic_for` of 2.

Comment: Hi @RossWilson, I do that because id 3 is pic_for id number 2 and id number 2 is pic_for id number 1. I do a while loop here because I can't using the same query to get id number 3, so I think I must do a looping to get all the id

Comment: If `$query->pic_for!=null` is true when you enter the loop it will be true forever, you're essentially writing `while (true) { do smething }`

Comment: what is your expeceted output

Comment: Hi @Manojkiran.A, I have edited my question, I want to, if I have id number 1, I get email id 2,3, and 4. And if I have id number 2, I only get email id 3.

Comment: sorry i can't get that what is the logic you are trying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried, but still the same, I just get id number 2 and number 4

Comment: @IkramShabri I edited the answer, try that one please

Comment: Hi @Sallmin Rexha, is that query for get all the table ? if I have one new data that pic_for is null, it's not what I want to get

ps: I have edited my question

Comment: Can you explain your code further? How exactly does it solve the requirement to get some data from the `email` columns?

Comment: Try this: $query = DB::table('users')->where('pic_for',$id)->whereNotNull('pic_for')->get(); and remove the while condition

Comment: Hi @SallminRexha, It's just same, I just get email id 2 and 4. I want to, if I have id number 1, I get email id 2,3, and 4. And if I have id number 2, I only get email id 3.

Comment: I don't want to try anything, but understand your code. If you make corrections that match the question better than the given answer, please edit your answer. Don't hide relevant information in the comment section

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, the first is I want to get value from id user, as example user 1 and then check where user in the table have been person in charge for this person (user 2), and after that check if another user is person in charge for user 2 or not